# Rails 3 returning a HTTP 406 Not Acceptable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following controller code:

```
  def create
    @admin = Admin.new(params[:admin])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.save
        redirect_to(@admin, :notice => 'Admin was successfully created.')
      else
        render :action => "new"
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.update_attributes(params[:admin])
        redirect_to(admin_admins_path, :notice => 'Admin was successfully updated.')
      else
        render :action => "edit"
      end
    end
  end
```

and the following routes:

```
           admin_admins GET    /admin/admins(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
           admin_admins POST   /admin/admins(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
        new_admin_admin GET    /admin/admins/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
       edit_admin_admin GET    /admin/admins/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
            admin_admin GET    /admin/admins/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
            admin_admin PUT    /admin/admins/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
            admin_admin DELETE /admin/admins/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/admins"}
```

Now, aside from the slightly whacky naming - the redirects always result in a 406 Not acceptable.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Remove `respond_to do |format|` blocks. Because you are not specifying to what format are you responding, e.g. `format.html { #your code here }` .
Check documentation of [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) how to use it properly.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar error, my controller was only responding to JSON. I needed it to respond to HTML also for the tests to work (which only makes sense):

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html
```

I received the error when trying to do: assert_redirected_to ad_url(ad)

Comment: This will only fix the problem if you use in conjunction with `respond_with @obj`. Otherwise, specifying `respond_to` in the controller is noop.

Comment: @maletor, not correct. 406 errors are generated regardless of whether `respond_with` is used or not.

Answer (score 1):

I started having this issue after a deploy in production, even tough everything was working fine in development.

After some 15 minutes of wasted time, I finally found out that **I had forgotten to commit some of the view files (like index.html.erb)**.

Using `tail -f log/production.log` on the server revealed: `FATAL -- : ActionController::UnknownFormat (SomeController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.`

In development the error didn't happen because, obviously, the view file was present.